# windows tkinter install python 3.7.4

Tags: python, tkinter

installed PYTHON 3.7.4 from the python.org website. Working on a windows 10 machine. everywhere it says tkinter should be part of it but it seems like it's not. I need help installing it.

Comment: if you have error message then show it. We can't see your screen and we can't read in your mind.

Comment: There's a checkbox that needs to be checked when you install in order for tkinter to be installed on Windows. I've not had any trouble recently with the installer installing tkinter.

Answer (score 1):

This is the official documentation for the standard library Tkinter created by the folks at Python Software Foundation :

[Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html)

This will definitely help you install, import and get started with Tkinter on your Windows system.

For importing errors while trying to use Tkinter, please note :

The root of the problem is that the Tkinter module is named Tkinter (capital "T") in python 2.x, and tkinter (lowercase "t") in python 3.x.

To make your code work in both Python 2 and 3 you can do something like this:

```
try:
    # for Python2
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    # for Python3
    from tkinter import *
```

But since you've already mentioned that you're on Python 3.7.4, this import statement will suffice :

```
import tkinter as tk
```

Comment: Thank you first of all, i have my tkinter working now. However, one thing i discovered....my python accepted the code as Tkinter, as it would in python 2. I downloaded 3.7.4 from the org website and i still have python 2 installed for some reason!!! i never had python installed in this machine before. Is there a way i can upgrade it to python 3? i already have tried downloading 3.7.4 file from the python.org website and ran the installer again, it still is the same thing!!

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter is built in with every Python installation.

I don't know if you typed the command wrong, but this is the proper way.

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

Note: There is a Capital T at the beginning of Tkinter.

In Python 3 for you,

```
import tkinter as tk
```

Note: You might accidentally deleted it in the folder of python so you could just download python again.

Answer (score 0):

Below from https://pypi.org/project/PySimpleGUI/:

Python 3.7
If you must run 3.7, try 3.7.2. It does work with PySimpleGUI with no known issues.

PySimpleGUI with Python 3.7.3 and 3.7.4+. tkinter is having issues with all the newer releases. Things like Table colors stopped working entirely. It's unclear if there's been a change that makes the tkinter API no longer working which means they are not backwards compatible. That would be a real shame. If so, more work needs to be done in PySimpleGUI

Comment: It's being fixed in tkinter in an upcoming release.  Some 3.8 release I believe has the fix.  It's discussed in the PySimpleGUI Issue on the topic and includes the tkinter bug information.

Answer (score -1):

Can you import tkinter by `import tkinter`?

Comment: The answer section should be for answers, not discussions.

Comment: I had less reputation for comment when i wrote that.

Comment: If that's the case, posting a comment in an answer is counter-productive because you'll end up losing reputation.

Comment: Does "import Tkinter" on the Python shell throw the same error too? I'd also like to see your code. Thank you.